# I am attempting to retrieve item names and prices from Best Buy, how do I get it to stop after the first price?

Tags: java, jsoup

Since the "amount" class is used for the item prices in the "we also recommend" section, it all the prices instead of just the main item price. How do I get it to stop looking for more prices after the first one? Here is my code:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class BestBuy {
  //retrieves item name and price from Best Buy
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "http://www.bestbuy.ca/en-CA/product/samsung-samsung-galaxy-tab-3-  8-0-16gb-android-4-2-tablet-with-exynos-4212-processor-white-sm-t310/10254746.aspx?path=8654a6d491c7d5a9465456671fa126e4en02";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        String amount = document.select(".amount").text();
        System.out.println("Price: " + amount);

        String name = document.select(".product-title").text();
        System.out.println("Item Name: " + name);

   }

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that `Element` you want is first one from selected `Elements` you can select it with `first()`.

Try with

```
String url = "http://www.bestbuy.ca/en-CA/product/samsung-samsung-galaxy-tab-3-8-0-16gb-android-4-2-tablet-with-exynos-4212-processor-white-sm-t310/10254746.aspx?path=8654a6d491c7d5a9465456671fa126e4en02";
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

String amount = document.select(".amount").first().text();
System.out.println("Price: " + amount);

String name = document.select(".product-title").first().text();
System.out.println("Item Name: " + name);
```

Ouptut:

```
Price: $229.99
Item Name: Samsung GALAXY Tab 3 8.0 16GB Android 4.2 Tablet with Exynos 4212 Processor - White
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used jsoup, but from their [API Reference](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/) it looks like the `Selector` class allows you to use CSS selectors such as `:eq`. See the [example here](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html):

> td:eq(0) finds the first cell of each row

You should be able to use the following:

```
String amount = document.select("span.amount:eq(0)").text();
```

Alternatively, and probably nicer, the `select` method returns an `Elements` that [implements `List`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29) so you can just use

```
String amount = document.select(".amount)").get(0).text();
```